# Only print ol.style.Text to polygon if text label fits inside its geometry

Tags: openlayers-3

In OpenLayers I use [ol.style.Text](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.Text.html) to add a text label to federal states polygons. The states have names of different length and also polygons of different sizes. It looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to only print the text marker if it fits inside its polygon (e.g. after zooming in)? For instance, in the above example Hessen, Thüringen, Sachsen and Bayern would be printed, but Rheinland-Pfalz, Saarland and Baden-Württemberg would be omitted because the text goes beyond its feature's geometry...

I know I can set the `font` property of an `ol.style.Text` to a particular size based on the `resolution` but this does not help here as text would still overlap the borders sometimes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible with help from the library. But you can use [CanvasRenderingContext2D#measureText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) in your vector layer's `stlyeFunction` to get the width of the label, and compare that with the extent's width of the polygon at a certain resolution, and decide based on that whether to render or not. You can also get smarter than using the extent's width, but it is probably a good enough approximation for many cases.

Comment: Thx! But how would I get the extent's width at the horizontal alignment where the text is to be printed? 1st I'd need to know where the text is printed (not always the middle). How? And then 2nd the extend of the polygon at this very horinzontal line? Again how?

Comment: The label point for the polygon is the point you get with `ol.geom.Polygon#getInteriorPoint()`. If you look up the source code of `ol.geom.flat.interiorpoint.linearRings`, you will see a variable named `maxSegmentLength`. That's the width you have available for labeling.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this (and if I have something running, then also post an answer here)